# Проверка XML по XSD с ошибками на русском языке

Tags: python, linux, xml, lxml

Одна из списка поставленных для проекта (python) задач - проверка XML по XSD, в результате которых должен выводится список ошибок на русском языке.
На данный момент используется lxml, без поддержки русского языка.

Перевода на русский язык не нашел. 
lxml использует пакет libxml2, перевода которого тоже не нашел.

Пока в отчаянии, вижу 2 варианта:

- ручная замена английских вхождений на русский по словарю в python;
- взять исходники libxml2, перевести ошибки и скомпилировать (возможно, будут проблемы в ходе реализации).

Есть ли какие-либо идеи помимо описанных выше?
Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Идея такая: скорее всего libxml2 умеет возвращать коды ошибок вместо текста. Нужно найти где текст ошибок прописан, перевести его, на определенный код ошибки выводить соответствующий текст на русском. Идею не проверял.

Comment: Как понял, посмотрев код libxml2, все ошибки описаны в файле xmlschemas.c - https://i.ibb.co/3cKVsDm/image.png. 
Нужная структура - xmlSchemaErr, для добавления ошибки используется функция xmlStrcat.
Попытаюсь поменять 1 строку для теста, скомпилировать, установить пакет и попробовать. Не уверен что сработает, но результат отпишу